# Pass PHP variable/value from one page to another

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have been trying to send the xml response I have stored in '$kxml' variable to the 'kycresult.php' page. I want to fetch the values from that xml and just print it. I am able to fetch the values if I store the xml in txt file and then get it using 'simplexml_load_file' but I don't want to create an extra file. Please let me know if there is a way to send the $kxml on next page.

```
$kycch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($kycch, CURLOPT_URL, $csckua_url);
curl_setopt($kycch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $kycxml);
curl_setopt($kycch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($kycch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$kycresult = curl_exec($kycch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($kycch);
$curl_error = curl_error($kycch);
curl_close($kycch);
// echo $kycresult;
$kxml = simplexml_load_string($kycresult);

if ($kxml['ret'] == 'Y') {
    // $ksuccess = 'Authentication Successful';
    header('location:Kycresult.php');
} else {
    $ksuccess = 'Authentication Failed';
}
```

Comment: Would a `GET` value work?`'location:Kycresult.php?kml=' . $kxml` Might not work or need additional considerations (e.g. urlencode, etc).. could also write it to a cookie; both these options would allow user/client to manipulate value

Comment: a `GET` request has a size limit of, I think, 2048 characters so if your XML is larger than that it will be truncated. Load the curl response data into a session variable and redirect to whichever page is to print the XML data so that you can then load that session data into simpleXML or DOMDocument etc

Answer (score 0):

As one of the possible solutions you can store the variable in session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['kxml'] = $kxml;
```

Then on the next page it will be available through

```
$kxml = $_SESSION['kxml'];
```

But actually it still stores in the auxiliary file by default under the hood.